# Timeout problems with the Riak Python Client with protocol buffers

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, riak

I'm seeing a strange but consistent behaviour from the Python Riak Client when connecting to my riak AWS cluster using protocol buffers. This short python snippet produces the error:

```
import time
import riak

client = riak.RiakClient(
            host='address_to_my_cluster_goes_here',
            http_port=8098,
            pb_port=8087,
            protocol='pbc'
         )

result = client.ping()

# Do something else for a while, > 60 seconds
time.sleep(61)

result = client.ping()
```

The last ping always throws an exception, with the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main_causing_exception.py", line 16, in <module>
    result = client.ping()
  File "C:\temp\venv\lib\site-packages\riak\client\transport.py", line 127, in wrapper
    return self._with_retries(pool, thunk)
  File "C:\temp\venv\lib\site-packages\riak\client\transport.py", line 69, in _with_retries
    return fn(transport)
  File "C:\temp\venv\lib\site-packages\riak\client\transport.py", line 125, in thunk
    return fn(self, transport, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\temp\venv\lib\site-packages\riak\client\operations.py", line 92, in ping
    return transport.ping()
  File "C:\temp\venv\lib\site-packages\riak\transports\pbc\transport.py", line 95, in ping
    msg_code, msg = self._request(MSG_CODE_PING_REQ)
  File "C:\temp\venv\lib\site-packages\riak\transports\pbc\connection.py", line 43, in _request
    return self._recv_msg(expect)
  File "C:\temp\venv\lib\site-packages\riak\transports\pbc\connection.py", line 50, in _recv_msg
    self._recv_pkt()
  File "C:\temp\venv\lib\site-packages\riak\transports\pbc\connection.py", line 71, in _recv_pkt
    % len(nmsglen))
  riak.RiakError: 'Socket returned short packet length 0 - expected 4'
```

If I do the `client.ping()` every 30 seconds or so, the error doesn't happen, indicating that it's some kind of socket keep-alive problem I'm seeing, but this does't seem like a solution robust enough for a production environment.

The error only occurs when using the `pbc` protocol setting and I've never seen it when using a `http` configured Riak Python Client.

I'm using Python 2.7.5 on a Win7-64 platform (though the error also occurs on our Ubuntu development server) in a virtual environment with the following packages and versions:

- protobuf (2.4.1)
- riak (2.0.1)
- riak-pb (1.4.1.1)

Any thoughts on what's going on and how to resolve it? Am I using the Python Riak Client in the wrong way?

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing on Ubuntu 12.04 with riak 2.0.2, riak-pb 1.4.1.1 and protobuf 2.4.1. I don't think you're using the client in the wrong way. I haven't figured out a robust solution to this either, unfortunately (except not using pbc...).

Comment: Hello - could you please file this as an issue on GitHub? https://github.com/basho/riak-python-client/issues/new

Answer (score 1):

You should use a newer version of Riak library.

There was an error with [`send`](https://github.com/basho/riak-python-client/blob/2.0.1/riak/transports/pbc/connection.py#L47) function in PBC transport, that was resolved here: https://github.com/basho/riak-python-client/issues/381